# Getting an UnknownHostException when trying to fetch data from flickr?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, flickr

I am trying to fetch the xml file from flickr. Here is my code:

```
public static final String TAG = "FlickrFetchr";
public static final String ENDPOINT = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/";
public static final String API_KEY = "d4db9623ea909f4d2a01c8c9667fd378";  //secret=0c764276c114d52f
public static final String METHOD_GET_RECENT = "flickr.photos.getRecent";
public static final String PARAM_EXTRAS = "extras";
public static final String EXTRA_SMALL_URL = "url_s";
private static final String XML_PHOTO = "photo";

String url = Uri.parse(ENDPOINT).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("method", METHOD_GET_RECENT)
    .appendQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)
    .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_EXTRAS, EXTRA_SMALL_URL)
    .build().toString();

String xmlString = getUrl(url);
```

When i debug, i see that the url is ([Docs](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=d4db9623ea909f4d2a01c8c9667fd378&extras=url_s))and it works, the xml file is there. But i am getting an exception that says **"Unable to resolve host "api.flickr.com": No address associated with hostname".**
Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you given the `INTERNET` permission?

Comment: If you are running an emulator, please restart it. This happens a lot. That exception is also thrown when the device has no internet connection.

Comment: @tolgap when i turned the internet of the device on, it worked thanks, you may write it as an answer and i can accept if you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as it was the case and you requested it, here's it as an answer.

If you are running an emulator, please restart it. This happens a lot. That exception is also thrown when the device has no internet connection.